# How can I make Heroku install devDependencies?

Tags: heroku, npm, gruntjs, dependency-management

I would like to have Heroku build my app after I push it so that I don't have to push the build folder up every time I make a change. However Heroku only installs the dependencies from the `package.json` and grunt (my build tool) and all of its components are in `devDependencies`. I would like to keep them there where they belong. What's the workaround here?

Comment: Could you use a custom buildpack like this? https://github.com/gcpantazis/heroku-buildpack-php-gruntjs

Answer (score 96, accepted):

**UPDATE**: as pointed out in the comments this is no more needed because since 2018 [heroku changed its default behaviour](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1376) and dev dependencies are automatically installed

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Heroku by default installs only the production dependencies, ignoring the development dependencies under `devDependencies`.

Setting the npm production variable to `false` do the trick:

```
heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
```

More info are available at the [Heroku Node.js Support page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process).

Comment: This sets your NODE_ENV to development, which may slow down your app.

Comment: @unblevable I don't think so: ```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
```

Comment: I did heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false and retarted dyno and the dev dependencies still won't install

Comment: Sorry, where should I type "heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false".? I don't use grunt, npm only. Is it possible to define envvars with package.json

Comment: @croraf it looks like you're not familiar with heroku CLI https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/command-line

Comment: Hi thanks. Yes I thought it is through their cli, which I dont use. But I found a way without it - through settings tab of the heroku application managment web page.

Comment: How do you do this in heroku-prebuild so you can keep the process in PRODUCTION? I thought I could call a bash script and `set` it there, but it doesn't install the devdeps that way.

Comment: If anyone's seeing this while using yarn, the equivalent is `YARN_PRODUCTION=false`

Comment: just like @valentin commented, since March 2018, heroku installs those by default, and vice versa should be done if you don't want it to
https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1376

Answer (score 19):

[Keeping](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#configuring-npm) `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` [`true`](https://www.dynatrace.com/blog/the-drastic-effects-of-omitting-node_env-in-your-express-js-applications/), I used [Heroku's script hooks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#heroku-specific-build-steps):

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "heroku-prebuild": "export NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false; export NODE_ENV=; NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false NODE_ENV=development npm install --only=dev --dev",
  "heroku-postbuild": "export NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true; export NODE_ENV=production;",
   ...
},
```

(Finally) worked for me.

Comment: I don't know whether it's an npm version thing, but for me the above solution worked with a different flag: `npm install --production=false`.

Answer (score 1):

```
scripts": {
  ...
  "heroku-prebuild": "npm install --only=dev"
}
```

This was enough for me. Thanks to PixnBits for the hint about heroku-prebuild.
Also - my problem was with babel.  I ended up moving babel-preset-es2015 and other presets into dependencies otherwise babel complained about presets.

Update: 8/11/2017 I've been having trouble with this. It seems like things have changed (and npm is on 5.3 now). But what I see is that the heroku-prebuild script is getting run, and then the post-install script is getting run (but I was only trying to install -dev).

So what I have been doing that works is to just run:

```
heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
```

And just leave it set that way. I'd love a better solution.

Comment: does this work for installing dependencies in subdirectories? suppose you have a package.json in a nested client folder

Answer (score 1):

To unintall dependencies you need to do these

1. Update NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION

   heroku config variable set

   NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
2. Add heroku-prebuild:

```js
    scripts": {
      ...
      "heroku-prebuild": "npm install"
    }
```

```
or
```

```js
    scripts": {
      ...
      "heroku-prebuild": "npm install --only=dev"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this in your build script `"build": "npm install --only=dev"` should in case you still want to perform more operations e.g transpiling your code with babel you can do something like this `"build": "npm install --only=dev && babel src --out-dir dist --copy-files"`

Answer (score 1):

Since 1 March 2018 Heroku [installs `devDependencies` by default](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1376), and then prunes them after the build step is done:

> By default, Heroku will install all dependencies listed in
> `package.json` under `dependencies` and `devDependencies`.
>
> After running the installation and build steps Heroku will strip out
> the packages declared under `devDependencies` before deploying the
> application.
>
> Heroku uses the lockfiles, either the `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`,
> to install the expected dependency tree, so be sure to check those
> files into git to ensure the same dependency versions across
> environments.

[Link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#package-installation)

Comment: They might say that, but trying the accepted answer worked for me anyway, in 2021 :/

Answer (score 1):

I found this highly confusing. Even though Heroku says that their [default since 2018](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1376) is to install all dependencies, they also set the env var `NODE_ENV=production` by [default](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#node_env-is-not-production). This is good because it causes/allows for pruning, but it is bad because it means [NPM will not install devDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install#description).

To avoid this without messing with environment variables and their possible side effects, we can append `--production=false` to npm and it will install dependencies and devDependencies.

In our case, in `package.json` in `scripts` we have a line:

```
"install": "npm i --prefix ... --production=false"
```

My answer similar to others above with the additional references that seem to explain why it's not actually working by default like Heroku suggests.